# Missing docs in ElasticSearch using tire/retire gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I am having problems with missing items from ElasticSearch index using tire gem.

```
tire/retire 0.6.2, 
ElasticSearch 0.90.13 (3 nodes)
```

Situation:
We have a postgres database of items which are also indexed in ES. 
Items are coming in periodically into our PG database and every 5 minutes a bulk store of unindexed items is made (we have an indexed flag) - usually about 50-100 items.
All items are in the bulk request (tire bulk_store), there are no errors in ES for any item (bulk store goes through ok).

Problem: 
Number of docs does not match the item count in PG database. Also some items are missing (I don't know which items are missing from index).
This difference is gradually increasing.

- id in ES is unique id in PG, there shouldn't be docs with same ID
- nothing weird is in ES logs
- all items are sent into bulk store
- we are checking for errors in bulk response, none found
- Force reindexing with tire rake task (`tire:import:model CLASS="Item" FORCE=1`) successfully indexes ALL items so docs count match pg count. Reindexing without FORCE does not improve docs count.

Any ideas why is this happening?

We have plans to upgrade from tire->elasticsearch gems and ES to 1.x, but before doing that I need to know why this is happening to prevent it in the future.

Example:

```
Items in pg DB: 1399669

"docs": {
        "count": 1399190,
       "deleted": 2766
      }
```